# Wordpress;how to remove_action from a Plugin to hide admin_notices created by another Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, action

I am a beginner to WP hooks, (actions and filters)
I was able to create a Plugin that shows all 4 admin notices in WP dashboard

here the Plugin-one code

```
    /* Start admin notices on */
  
function display_admin_notice() {
    ?>
    <div class ="notice notice-success is-dismissible"><p>Congratulatios! it seems you have a nice success notice</p></div>
    <div class = "notice notice-error"><p>What a nice error message</p> </div>
    <div class = "notice notice-warning"><p>WARNING!!! site about to blow up in pieces</p></div>
    <div class = "notice notice-info is-dismissible"><p>INFO - you must renew license</p></div>

    <?php
  }
  add_action( 'admin_notices', 'display_admin_notice' );
  
/* Stop admin notices on */
```

it works perfectly.

Now I have another plugin that hides ALL notifications

```
/* Start Block ALL admin notices */

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'block_dismissable_admin_notices');
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'block_dismissable_admin_notices');

function block_dismissable_admin_notices() {
   echo '<style>.wp-core-ui .notice{ display: none !important; }</style>';
}

/* Stop Block ALL admin notices */
```

it works fine too

BUT I need to REMOVE the action from the first Plugin, NOT to hide all notifications, I mean, is there a way to get the

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'display_admin_notice'
```

from the first Plugin and remove_action so the Plugin hides/block ONLY the admin_notices from THAT plugin and NOT from all  the Wordpress  core or   another plugins?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading code and then unloading it (pointless) you could add an if statement to conditionally check if the action hook is needed.

eg.

```
$noticesOn = true; // Conditional setting could be here

if ( $noticesOn == true ) {
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'block_dismissable_admin_notices');
    add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'block_dismissable_admin_notices');
}
```

Comment: Hi, Ryan and thanks. I don´t understand, my apologies. I need to hook or whatever the word,  to add_action( 'admin_notices', 'display_admin_notice' (plugin one) from ANOTHER plugin and I do not know how to get that part done to add a block/hide code like that you point

Answer (score 0):

ok, I finally got it

this is the solution

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_my_action' );
function remove_my_action()
{
global $wp_filter;
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'display_admin_notice');
}
```

it works perfect